# Triangular grid with CSS or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a design for a site and want to have a triangular grid in one of the sections sort of like the image here:

[image: example image of triangular grid]

I'm not to sure on how to approach this as all the methods I've come across don't do the job well.

Here's my first attempt using css http://jsfiddle.net/df5wx36e/2/

```
.container {
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 1200px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.up {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 0 200px 200px 200px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
    float: left;
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    margin-left: -200px;
}

.up p {
    text-align: center;
    top: 80px;
    left: -47px;
    position: relative;
    width: 93px;
    height: 53px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.down {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 200px 200px 0 200px;
    border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
    float: left;
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    margin-left: -200px;
}

.down p {
    text-align: center;
    top: -140px;
    left: -47px;
    position: relative;
    width: 93px;
    height: 53px;
    margin: 0px;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="down">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="up">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="down">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="up">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="down">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>     
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="up"> 
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="down">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="up">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="down">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="up">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="down">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="up">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="down">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="up">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
  <div class="down">
      <p>some info<p>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the contents are not flush with the triangles and will overflow easily. Also with creating teh triangles using css borders I'm not able to set the background of the triangles or really have any dimensions to contain the content.

Ideally the grid needs to be 1200px wide and contain 4 full triangles per row and with half or semi triangles on the ends depending on the row.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 5 per row?  Are both orientations of the triangles (point facing up vs point facing down) supposed to contain content?

Comment: Hi Joseph, yeah I wanted both orientations to contain content. I'm not to fussed about the number of triangles per row exactly. Just need a better method of creating a triangular grid than I could come up with myself as its not fit for purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to achieve is possible with [Slantastic](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/slantastic/demo.html), that is if you want the contents of your triangles to be more than just 93px **rectangles**... I haven't played with it myself (never had a project that required it), but it looks like the right tool for the job.